# Why is "will" used in a time clause with "when"?

Tags: future-tense

1. When it **will be** ready, it will get out.

Why is it not

2. When it **is** ready, it will get out

Future with clause time is rarely used: so why is it used in this clause,"when it will be ready"?
I think the first sentence means that I will tell you now when the  merchandise will be ready (may be a fixed date) but it is not ready now. The second means that I will let you know as soon as the merchandise is ready.

It is the same problem for these sentences

3. It will take up to 72 hours until it **will be** ready.
   or
4. It will be 72 hours until it **is** ready

I think the first one is only possible in this case.

Comment: change it by stuff (hope this one is singular)

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the one that you think is correct but seems confusing to you is actually wrong. The correct usage is your numbers 2 and 4, and numbers 1 and 3 are wrong.

Comment: but i ve seen this " it would up to 72 hours till the goods would be ready" in the past so that should be in present  "it will be up to 72 hours till it will be ready "

Comment: @YvesLefol Even if you’ve seen it, it was wrong. It should have been “It would be up to 72 hours until the goods were ready”.

Comment: @YvesLefol when you see sentences or expression that seem to be wrong make a note of three things: **1.** Where you saw it, (online, in a book/magazine, in a movie) **2** Who said it (native or non-native speaker). **3** The context. Unless you provide this information in your question, it's going to be really difficult for a competent English speaker to say sentences 1 and 3  are "acceptable" , "grammatical" or "dialectal".

Comment: ...okay, I found one: I put a prescription request for my wife's painkillers on Monday and was told  that it would be up to72 hours until it would be ready for pickup. But it doesn't really match your context. – FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Sep 20 at 12:10

Comment: I disagree with @MikeScott and find that (_until it would be ready_)  perfectly acceptable.   However, in the present tense we would say "It will be up to 72 hours until it is ready".

Comment: why with present "it is ready" and with past "it would be ready " instead of it was